# passing data from view to a controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

well I have a problem. I'm building a list of name.this name are obtained from a mysql query.The controller receives those names from model and after passes to a view and view prints out them in a list.When you click in a name another page opens showing every details about name (phone,ecc...). My problem is how I can do this.I mean I know how create a list this is how I do:

```
<ul>

        <?php foreach ($users as $item): ?>

            <li><a href=""><?php echo $item->name . " " . $item->surname; ?></a></li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

When I click on the link of name and surname I have to go to a page that contains details of that name and surname.How can I do this? I have to pass name and surname to a controller from a view and do a query ?

Comment: It's a bit vague, but I think you'd be sending GET variables in that href, and then the controller would read these and do the magic.

Comment: @AramKocharyan what do you mean send GET variables in that href? how can I do? can do an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you have structured your controller and views, but you could use a structure such as this for users, where uid is the unique user id:

```
href="users.php?uid=123"
```

`users.php` would then use the GET variable `uid` to load the request the user information from your model and then communicate that information to your view. Reading in the GET variable would be like so:

```
if ( isset($_GET['uid']) ) {
    $uid = $_GET['uid'];
    // Load info from model and present in view
} else {
    // Handle invalid or unspecified users, perhaps show all available users
}
```

Once you have built the basic functionality you can employ Apache mod_rewrite rules such as Sureround has used to make the url pretty.

Answer (score 2):

make your links like this:

```
 <li>
   <a href="/user/get_user_details/<?php echo $item->name; ?>">
     <?php echo $item->name . " " . $item->surname; ?>
   </a>
 </li>
```

this will go to the controller user, method get_user_details and will pass the $item->name as a parameter to the method. use this (or whatever property of item you pass) to show the details of that item.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the unique ID for each name via the URL for example, "/users/getuser/1". If your controller is called "users" then you would create function called getuser and use  $this->uri->segment(3) to retrieve the ID from the URL. YOu can then store that into a variable which you pass to your model to get the details for the record and then load your User detail view.

```
function getuser()
{
  $userID = $this->uri->segment(3);

  // Then just load your model pass your $userID and load your view
}

In your href you would just output <?= "/users/getuser/" . $item->id; ?>
```